# MS Access, How to pass parameter to subquery?

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters, subquery

i've got two tables. one contains all my customers, another one all their orders.
i would like to create an sql query that looks like this:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Firstname, c.Lastname, 
       (
        SELECT count(orderID) 
          FROM tbl_orders o 
         WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
       ) as OrderCount
  FROM tbl_customers c;
```

The problem I have with this is that access keeps asking me for the parameter "CustomerID" which would be used in the subselect WHERE clause. Obviously, I'd like to figure it out automatically. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you sure both tables have a column called `CustomerID`?

Comment: Right: unexpected parameter pop-up generally means that a field name was misspell3d.

Comment: Just for the record: You can use data from parent query in subquery in MySQL too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no apparent reason, it should work. Maybe you made a mispell on one of your fields. Check if CustomerID is part of tbl_orders & tbl_customers.

You can find some information about sub query thru the following link : [SubQueryDoc](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html)

Answer (score 2):

Why not trying with a join and a group by ? it seems simpler and richer to me.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, c.Firstname, c.Lastname, count(o.orderId) as Orders, max(o.OrderDate) as LastOrder
FROM tbl_customers c LEFT JOIN tbl_orders o 
ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.Firstname, c.Lastname
```

Such a query can be designed visually in the query design view. You can then switch to SQL View, and copy or edit the generated SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Remove alias "c" on both main and sub query.